# Nested select statement with from and where all being unique?

Tags: sql

Hello I am trying to write a nested query for different applications in my database.

The following SQL code is one "statement" that returns a specific group of applications

```
FROM APPL
WHERE APPL.CRE_TS >= to_date('20190801','yyyymmdd') and APPL.CRE_TS < to_date('20190802','yyyymmdd')
AND CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%C'
```

it returns all the applications that end in a C and follow that specific date.

I want to make a query where the FROM stays the same for all of them, and the date stays the same but the only difference is the line

```
AND CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%C'
```

where I would change the %C to something else. What is the cleanest query to do preform this?

Comment: Please explain your answer. `I want to make a query where the FROM stays the same for all of them, and the date stays the same but the only difference is the line` - what does that mean? Are you looking for one query that will allow you to have multiple `CPTR_APPL_ID` values? Which values do you want?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all really help!

Comment: Hey guys I apologize, I can't share the database it's all proprietary. there are different types of applications in the database that end in a certain character like B or C or V or whatever I just need to count each of them and put the count in its own column. @JerryM.@GordonLinoff

Comment: Your DBMS type isn't proprietary and it's impossible for us to help you without knowing that. We also can't write the rest of the SQL with you without the full query. You can spoof data and make it representative -- I do all the time.

Comment: @JerryM. Im not sure if the DBMS is necessary I just need to extend the CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%C' so it works with B or A or K in the same statement

Comment: You could wrap up the common logic in a view and then query `select * from ApplicationsView where CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%C'` You could even add a column to the view that contains just the final character so the filter could be more like `APPL_CATEGORY = 'C'`

Answer (score 0):

you could add the other conditions in an `OR` like this :

```sql
FROM 
    APPL
WHERE 
    APPL.CRE_TS >= to_date('20190801','yyyymmdd') 
    AND APPL.CRE_TS <  to_date('20190802','yyyymmdd')
    AND 
        (CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%C'
        OR CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%A'
        OR CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%B')
```

PS. format your code so that it is readable.

EDIT: Based on your comment saying you want it for all ending characters, along with a count, what you need is a `GROUP BY` along with `RIGHT()`.

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(CPTR_APPL_ID, 1)
   ,COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    APPL
WHERE 
    APPL.CRE_TS >= to_date('20190801','yyyymmdd') 
    AND APPL.CRE_TS <  to_date('20190802','yyyymmdd')
GROUP BY RIGHT(CPTR_APPL_ID, 1)
```

Comment: Im not sure this would work for my situation, if it does I apologize I basically just need to count all the different types of applications based on their ending character and have a table named I know I would use AS